# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

Tags: java, spring

Just joined and just started learning spring boot. I wrote my first application which is as below:

SpringBootApiApp.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication

public class SpringBootApiApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApiApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.springbootquickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringBootQuickStart</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringBootApplication</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>    
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

</project>
```

When I run the java class in STS as a Java application, I see the below error, I don't see a compilation error though:Please help me fixing it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at SpringBootApiApp.main(SpringBootApiApp.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: is your spring jars present in your classpath ?

Comment: Yes. I can share the screen shot.Not able to attach the screen shot here, But there are.

Comment: yup share the screen-shot

Answer (score 1):

Maybe run Maven -> Update project (so dependencies will be downloaded)
If maven update fails then your settings.xml for maven is bad, repositories are misconfigured forexample.
Check which settings.xml is used by Eclipse at Windows->Preferences->Maven->User Settings

Comment: Settings.xml is not found on my PC. What must be its content.

Comment: Have you installed maven manually to your PC to any location or you are using embedded maven in eclipse?

Comment: I have installed maven manually. It works now as I created a spring project in eclipse. Earlier, I created maven project. Thanks a lot for your prompt responses.

Comment: But to know more, while there were no compile errors, and though the appropriate jars are added to the class path and maven works perfectly fine, would like to understand, in what scenarios this error occurs and how to fix it.